# Explain argument definition of in NEST API

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, elasticsearch, nest

```
// Summary:
//     The text_phrase_prefix is the same as text_phrase, expect it allows for prefix
//     matches on the last term in the text

public QueryContainer MatchPhrasePrefix<T>(Func<MatchPhrasePrefixQueryDescriptor<T>, IMatchQuery> selector);
```

Could someone explain what `Func<MatchPhrasePrefixQueryDescriptor<T>, IMatchQuery>` is?

Comment: Is this a real method ? Shouldn't that be `MatchPhrasePrefix<T>(.....` ??? This wouldn't compile as far as I can tell.

Comment: No, It's the definition of method given in query container.
please  explain the ?
MtachPhrasePrefix(Func<MatchPhrasePrefixQueryDescriptor<T>, IMatchQuery> selector )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a method that accepts a delegate/method/lambda expression as an argument that itself, accepts a `MatchPhrasePrefixQueryDescriptor<T>` as an argument and returns an `IMatchQuery` instance.

It is part of the fluent API of [NEST, the high level .NET Elasticsearch client.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/index.html) [The client supports both fluent API and an object initializer syntax.](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net#searching-for-documents) As others have pointed out, the method is generic, `MatchPhrasePrefix<T>`

To use

```
public class Document
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
}

var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchPhrasePrefix(p => p
            .Field(f => f.Property1)
            .Query("Prefix phrase")
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: What does .Query(" Prefix phrase") means?

Comment: That's the input to the `match_phrase_prefix` query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html

Comment: Thank you so much sir :)

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped, feel free to upvote and if it provides a solution, you can accept the answer.